# Xamarin Forms cross-platform map issue on Android

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, maps, cross-platform

After upgrading Xamarin Forms and Maps to version 2.3.3.193, on my Android app, I now receive the following error when I attempt to display a map:

> {Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ViewRenderer}
>   {System.MissingMemberException}
>   Android.Gms.Maps.MapView.get_Map' not found

Any idea what is going on? It worked before the update. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Screen shots of my Nuget manager showing 2.3.3.193 as latest stable version.

[image]

Comment: I've checked the "Include prerelease" in NuGet manager and I couldn't find the release version 2.3.3.193 both for `Xamarin.Forms` and `Xamarin.Forms.Maps`, how did you update your packages? The latest stable version by my side is 2.3.3.180.

Comment: It shows up in visual studio enterprise.  I update through nuget.  It said there was a consolidated update for xamarin forms and maps.  I installed that and got 2.3.3.193.

Comment: I am only doing stable releases.

Comment: By my side it is like this: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLWg4.png), I also checked the Xamarin version, by my side it is V4.2.1, and I didn't find a newer version either, strange thing.

Comment: Well then I suggest you talk with someone at msft as to how I got this.  You are not showing your updates tab either.  As I mentioned 193 appeared to be part of a consolidated update, not a stand alone update for forms or maps.  You can see my screenshot which clearly shows 193 as not a pre release.

Comment: Also not Xamarin Forms Maps no longer has a green check mark by it in the list of installed packages thus supporting my theory that it has been rolled into Xamarin Forms (via the consolidated update) and is no longer a stand alone component

Comment: Since no one from MS or Xamarin is addressing this, I have reported the defect to MS via Visual Studio.  Hope that will get the ball rolling.

Comment: To get Xamarin Forms 2.3.3.193 

1.   Create a new cross platform project in Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise
2.   Open the Nuget package manager.  
3.   Go to the Update tab and install all updates (7 I think)
4.   The funny thing to note is that after you install all the updates, only the Andriod project shows 2.3.3.193.  
4.   After you do this, the consolidated tab of Nuget will show 1 consolidated update.  
5.   The consolidated update show Xamarin Forms V 2.3.3.193.  Install it and all projects will be running 2.3.3.193

Comment: Here is the long winded root of the problem and a work around. Or wait till they update it correctly. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/88135/xamarin-forms-map-error-on-andriod-after-updating-xamarin-forms-and-maps-to-2-3-3-193

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin.Forms.Maps 2.3.3.193 requires Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps version to be 29.0.0.1. Not 29.0.0.1 or higher!

[Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tp4z.png)

From your screenshot, you have 42.1001.0

I'm in the same boat. Still got to use the nuget package built in march 2016!

Answer (score 1):

### Update

The issue is fixed in the latest stable version of Xamarin Forms [2.3.4.224](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms/2.3.4.224).

### Original Answer

Refer to https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=52625 for discussion about this issue.

Google removed their java `getMap` method which had been obsoleted for some time (even in 29.0.0.1 you can see the equivalent `Map` property is marked obsolete). The Forms renderer uses the `Map` property (so the underlying java `getMap` method), which no longer exists in newer versions of play services, so crash occurs.  The Forms renderer will need to change to use the `GetMapAsync` method.

Rob Lyndon (Bugzilla discussion) created the patch you could use: https://www.nuget.org/packages/XamarinForms.Maps.Android.TemporaryPatch

I couldn't use the patch directly from Nuget due to PCL profile missmatch, so I ended up doing the following:

1. Copy [MapRenderer](https://github.com/SpiegelSoft/XamarinForms.Maps.Android.TemporaryPatch/blob/master/XamarinForms.Maps.Android.TemporaryPatch/MapRenderer.cs) from the patch to your Android project. Make sure to adjust namespace
2. Extend Map in your PCL project

> public class CustomMap : Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Map { }

3. Create custom renderer in Android project

> ```
> [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomMap), typeof(MapRenderer))]
> namespace StanleySteemer.Nimbus.Mobile.Renderers
> {
>     public class CustomMapRenderer : MapRenderer {}
> }
> ```

4. Use CustomMap instead of Map in your View